# ASP.Net MVC 5 MF not creating enum column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to ASP.Net and I'm trying to develop a model that represents Logs from a system, but the controller wizard (that creates the scaffolding views), and the code first approach are not creating all the columns.

This is my model's definition:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public enum SystemComponents : byte
    {
        Component1, Component2, Component3
    }

    public enum LogMessageCategory : byte
    {
        Warning, Error, Debug, Log
    }

    public class LogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Log
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public SystemComponents AffectedComponent;

        [Required]
        public LogMessageCategory MessageCategory;

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), Name = "EventDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Foreign Key that represents the event's emisor.
        /// This can be both a User, or a System component
        /// </summary>
        public int ActorID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Foreign Key that represents the event's emisor.
        /// This can be both a User, or a System component
        /// </summary>
        public int ComponentID { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, what's the correct way to display this property in Views that use Resources (for internationalization)? (as this model's instances are going to be created by the system, I don't care abut how to display a field in a Create view)

Also, additional question, do I have to declare public all my properties in order to use them? Online tutorials do not explain this, but fields are not created in databases if not.

P.D. I think I'm using EF 6.0 (VS 2013 Premium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to expose them as properties, instead of public fields.

```
[Required]
public SystemComponents AffectedComponent{ get; set; }

[Required]
public LogMessageCategory MessageCategory{ get; set; }
```